# decision tree in R using a training dataset

Tags: r

I am trying to create a decision tree in R using the following training data set

```
structure(list(Color = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), Size = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), Act = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), Age = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), Inflated = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("F", "T"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))
```

I have used the following code

```
Training1 <- as.data.frame(unclass(Training1), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
tree1<- ctree(Inflated ~ ., Training1)
```

And it isn't plotting a decision tree, any advise on how to plot this

when I

```
plot(tree1)
```

I get this image[image]

Comment: Did you try plotting your `ctree` object? i.e. try `plot(ctree(Inflated ~ ., Training1))`

Comment: yes, I have added a picture of what I get

Comment: Thanks for adding that - the issue is with your tree, not the plot. Your current tree is just one node

Comment: I don't know how to add more nodes, that's the issue I need to solve but not sure how to

Comment: You haven't explained to problem you are trying to address with a decision tree. Decision **tree** construction requires features and outcomes so you can split into nodes and branches. You've only given it a single vector so all it can plot is the proportions in that vector. No "decision" is possible. You should look at the examples in `?ctree`

Comment: I have read the information for ctree and still do not understand how I get it to run with more branches